# `date` command doesn't work as expected under fish shell

Tags: command-line, fish

I have written numerous aliases and functions using fish shell. yet this one bit threw me off guard. Can someone help me to understand what's going wrong and possibly how to fix them?

**Problem**: Define an alias/function called `ep` which prints human readable date by accepting an epoch number

i.e I want as below

```
nehem@ubuntu ~/c/t/c> ep 1569548631
Fri 27 Sep 11:43:51 AEST 2019
```

The command I'm planning to use is `-d` option of the well-known `date` command

```
nehem@ubuntu ~/c/t/> date -d '@1569548631'
Fri 27 Sep 11:43:51 AEST 2019
```

Now here's my fish function,

```
function ep
        set cmd "date -d @$argv[1]"
        $cmd 
end
```

Now upon executing I'm getting `date -d @1569548631: command not found` error, though I feel it's such a valid command.

```
nehem@ubuntu ~/c/t/n> ep 1569548631
date -d @1569548631: command not found
~/conf/new.fish (line 449): 
    $cmd
    ^
in function “ep”
    called on standard input
    with parameter list “1569548631”
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a subcommand i.e. the command "date" in your "set" command:

```
set cmd "date -d @$argv[1]"
```

You have to use **parentheses** instead of double quotes:

```
set cmd (date -d @$argv[1])
```

[Here](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-do-i-run-a-subcommand-the-backtick-doesn-t-work) you can find the related documentation.

If you also want to write your variable to stdout you have to echo it:

```
echo $cmd
```

Instead of just

```
$cmd
```